# Zend ACL deny parent roles only from child role's resources

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I am trying to implement ACL in Zend Framework. I want parent roles to have access to all resources except to resources allowed to child role(s). I have following code so far:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$acl->addRole('visitor')
    ->addRole('subscriber', 'visitor')
    ->addRole('editor', 'subscriber')
    ->addRole('admin', 'editor')
    ->addRole('superadmin', 'admin')
    ->allow();

$acl->addResource('index')
    ->addResource('blog')
    ->addResource('users')
    ->addResource('admin');

acl->allow('subscriber', 'blog', 'index')
    ->allow('editor', 'blog', array('add', 'edit'))
    ->allow('admin', 'admin')
    ->allow('superadmin', 'users');
```

I want "visitor" to have access to **all resources** *except* to resources allowed to child roles subscriber, editor, admin, superadmin. Same for all other roles and resources. "visitor" will have access to all resources but not to resources allowed to child roles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working with Zend_Acl and I think I got what you mean. The "problem" is that, by default, Zend denies access to every resource, while you don't specify some user has rights to have access to the desired resource.

It means that when u create your ACL (roles, resources, permissions), you have to inform that you want to give permission to the Visitor to access each resource he can access.

I believe Zend works this way for security, because this way you can be sure that just users that u granted access will have the right to interact with the specified resource.

Answer (score 0):

"subscriber" is not the parent of "visitor", but is actually its **child**. Therefore, subscriber inherit all resources and privileges of visitor.
You didn't really ask any question but it seems that what you want is the expected behavior of Zend_Acl.

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$acl->addRole('visitor')
->addRole('subscriber', 'visitor')
->addRole('editor', 'subscriber')
->addRole('admin', 'editor')
->addRole('superadmin', 'admin');

$acl->addResource('index')
->addResource('blog')
->addResource('users')
->addResource('admin');

$acl->allow('subscriber', 'blog', 'index')
->allow('editor', 'blog', array('add', 'edit'))
->allow('admin', 'admin')
->allow('superadmin', 'users');
```

adding `$acl->allow('visitor', 'index', 'index')`, *visitor* now has access to the *index* page, and its children have also access to the index page. But *visitor* doesn't have access to the resource *blog* and privilege *index*, **only subscriber and its children have access to this page**.

You should read the [documentation of Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html), there are lots of good examples available.

Comment: but using this code visitor will be denied access from blog's view action `$acl->isAllowed('visitor', 'blog', 'view');` or any other resource.

Comment: Correct. So basically, you want you visitor to be a superadmin and your superadmin to be a visitor? If not, what resources do you want to give to your visitor?